# How do to fill NaN's in a pandas dataframe with random 1's and 0's

Tags: pandas

How to replace the NaN values in a pandas dataframe with random 0's and 1's?

```
df.fillna(random.randint(0,1))
```

seems to fill the NaN's in certain columns with all 1's or all 0's

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Check the output of `random.randint(0,1)` and that should explain why.  Essentially the statement says: `df.fillna(0)` or `df.fillna(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Creating a dummy Dataframe

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [100,np.nan,27000,np.nan]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])


# Replacing NAN in a particular column

a = df.Price.isnull()
rand_int = np.random.randint(2, size=a.sum())
df.loc[a,'Price' ] = rand_int
print(df)

# For entire dataframe

for i in df:
    a = df[i].isnull()
    rand_int = np.random.randint(2, size=a.sum())
    df.loc[a, i ] = rand_int
print(df)
```

Comment: It is a simple code. I am fetching the column. Checking if it has any NAN replacing it with 0 and 1 randomly using np,random.randint function.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I wanted but I keep getting the errors TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' and IndexError: 0 when I run it

Comment: If this is the answer @brown_squirrel, may you up-vote and select it as accepted. If not, please provide a reproducible example.